# Returning a value from a thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Hello i am having a hard time understanding how a value is returned from a thread in c. I have this working example:

```
#define NTHREADS 4
void *neg (void * param) {
    int *l;
    l=(int *) param;
    int *r=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *r=-*l;
    return ((void *) r);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    int arg[NTHREADS];
    int err;
    for(long i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++) {
    arg[i]=i;
    err=pthread_create(&(threads[i]),NULL,&neg,(void *) &(arg[i]));
    if(err!=0)
        error(err,"pthread_create");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++) {
        int *r;
        err=pthread_join(threads[i],(void **)&r);
            printf("Resultat[%d]=%d\n",i,*r);
        free(r);
        if(err!=0)
            error(err,"pthread_join");
    }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What i find hard to understand is the following:

the function neg returns a pointer * r casted in (void *) pointing to a value in the heap. Thus returning an adress to the heap basically. Then in pthread_join we get that return value by doing  &r (which by itself seems illogical? grab the adress of an adress?) then  casting to a pointer of a pointer? Why do we do that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "neg returns a pointer * r": The pointer value returned is the value of the variable `r`, not `*r`.

Comment: "*grab the adress of an adress?*" no, you pass the address of the pointer variable `r`, this tells `pthread_join()` were to write the threads result to.

Comment: `int *r = malloc(sizeof(int));` - no need to cast result of `malloc`.  In `main()`:  `void *r; int result; err=pthread_join(threads[i], &r); result = *(int*)r;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code, which is perfectly valid and prints "5 5 5 5".

```
int x = 5;
int *p = &x;
int **pp = &p;
int ***ppp = &pp;
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x, *p, **pp, ***ppp);
return 0;
```

C allows you to have any depth of pointers, initialized with a corresponding number of address-of operators. In your example, you allocated an `int *` and the function must return a `void **`, so you have to dereference the result twice and cast it, which you accomplished by casting the `int *`.

So,"grab the adress of an adress?" <s>Yup!</s> Well, the address of a *pointer*, which may hold the address of an int, or another pointer.

Comment: Side notes, your `error(...)` call looks incorrect, it should have 2 `int` parameters then a `char *`. Also, putting the loop variable inside the `for()` requires >= c99.

Comment: An address does not have an address. On the other hand a pointer variable holding an address has.

Comment: I see, so basically because pthread_join expects a void ** we reference it (thats the word right? to add a pointer on top) in the neg fct then dereference it in the main afterwards. Next question is then why does pthread_join require void ** ? EDIT:Seen this happen to other situations aswell like passing on a pointer to a struct to a function is also passed on as double pointer **

Comment: + actually the whole pthread_join syntax is weird, in almost all other pthread functions you would usually pass a ptr of type pthread_t * but in join you use a pthread_t for some reason

Comment: Yeah, if you want to set a pointer by means of a function call, you pass the address of that pointer, and the function takes a `**` parameter. That's usually as weird as it gets, although I've seen code that uses `***`. Anyway `pthread_join` returns an int error code, but also wants the `void *` return value of the thread function, so it makes sense there.

Comment: Thanks i get it all now, just one last question. Why does pthread_join take a pthread_t structure and not a pointer to one as argument like most of the other pthreads functions? (Possible exam question on my upcomming exam :p)

Comment: I suppose it was a design decision. `pthread_t` is an opaque type, so you're not supposed to depend on it being an int/struct/pointer, but it is typically an unsigned long int. Except for `pthread_create`, the other pthreads functions pass the `pthread_t` parameter by value not pointer. Good luck on your exam. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Then in pthread_join we get that return value by doing &r (which by
>   itself seems illogical? grab the adress of an adress?) then casting to
>   a pointer of a pointer? Why do we do that?

First thing you need to understand is that the *thread* function(s) do not return the value directly; they send the value to the pthreads library using `pthread_exit()` or returning a value (as in your example) and 
it's retrieved with a call to `pthread_join()` (by using the thread identifier). Since the return value is a pointer, you have to 
pass a pointer to pointer to retrieve it from `pthread_join()` function.

For the understanding purposes, consider this pseudo code:

```
/* thread */
void *neg(void *arg)
{
    return ptr; // let's say "ptr" is stored in the library as "retval_thread_id"
}

int pthread_joing(pthread_t thread_id, void **retval)
{
    *retval = retval_thread_id;
}

int main(void)
{
    rc = pthread_join(threads[i],(void **)&r);
}
```

So, how can you retrieve the pointer `retval_thread_id` from `pthread_join()` without using a pointer to pointer?
This is nothing different than passing a ptr-to-ptr to a function and the function stores at the pointee of the passed pointer:

```
void func(int **p) 
{
    *p = malloc(10 * sizeof *p);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    func(&p);
}
```

By the way , all the casts you do (except the one in the call to `pthread_join()` -- You wouldn't this either if you declared `r` as `void *r;`.) are unnecessary. A void pointer can be assigned to any other data pointer in C without a cast.